# exploration Program goal returning as false , not sure what to do next

Tags: pddl

So Im writing a PDDL for mars exploration but it shows
Suspected timeout.

ff: goal can be simplified to FALSE. No plan will solve it

What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74158344/edit) your question to add your PDDL domain and problem, aka [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The title should mention "FF" and "PDDL"

Answer (score 1):

That's not timeout: FF proved that it's impossible to reach the goal.
"Simplified" means it didn't even need to search, so it's probably a very fundamental modelling problem.

Try changing the goal to the preconditions of actions that you think should be achievable.

Comment: its still showing the same error when I did that

Comment: Start slow: for instance, add as goal one action that you think should be applicable. That should return a plan with only that action.